# How to reload cell in jupyter notebook? After OSError: [Errno 12] Cannot allocate memory

Tags: deep-learning, tensorflow, jupyter

I got an error:
`OSError: [Errno 12] Cannot allocate memory`
I deleted some files. And I have free memory. I don't want start learning again from first epoch. (I got an error in last epoch).

I use jupyter notebook.
I have 19 .h5 file in my output file.
Can I click something to save my last .h5 file?

[image: Print Screen]

Edit: 
[image: Media]

Comment: Are you using tensorflow?

Comment: Yes. I use tensorflow.

Comment: If you are using tensorflow and your kernel is still alive you can just resume the training because the variables hold what they've learnt until now. The current snapshot of your graph, you can be stored it.

Comment: Yes. My kernel is alive. How can I resume the training?

Comment: just run the sess.run cell. Your current values are still available.

Comment: Ok. I should click on In:[27] (cell with my error) and then run?

Comment: I guess it's better to put your history in another cell.

Comment: I added a new Printscreen. Good?

Comment: And now run In:[27] and then In:[] (cell with history)

Comment: I guess if it's risky, you can omit that magic stuff too.

Comment: Ech. I run it but this cause that proces again but from next cell. My modified cell will be executed after at the end. :P

Comment: I didn't understand :)

Answer (score 1):

One option is to add TensorFlow [Checkpoint](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/Checkpoint) which allows for the saving and reloading of training.